# Преобразование даты в java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, дата

Проблема такая: Нужно внести в базу данных дату и время в соответствующие поля. Но происходит непонятная ситуация. На уровне выполнения запроса происходит преобразования даты и времени. Закономерности преобразования времени я не выявил. С датой же от вносимой на день назад. Использую MySQL, java.sql.Date и Time.

Код, выполняющий запрос к базе данных.

```
@Override
    public int addNewSaleSum(SaleSum new_sale_sum) {
        int id_sale = 0;
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO esteamerbase.sale_sum " +
                "(ID_CARD, ID_USER, BUY_SUM, CASHBEK_SUM, GIFT_SUM, DATE_BUY, TIME_BUY,COMMENT, SPOSOB_OPLAT) " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, new_sale_sum.getId_card());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, new_sale_sum.getId_user());
            preparedStatement.setFloat(3, new_sale_sum.getBuy_sum());
            preparedStatement.setFloat(4, new_sale_sum.getCashbek_sum());
            preparedStatement.setFloat(5, new_sale_sum.getGift_sum());
            preparedStatement.setDate(6, new_sale_sum.getDate_byu());//Преобразование происходит тут
            preparedStatement.setTime(7, new_sale_sum.getTime_buy());Преобразование происходит тут
            preparedStatement.setString(8, new_sale_sum.getComment());
            preparedStatement.setString(9, new_sale_sum.getSposob_oplat());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                id_sale = resultSet.getInt(1);
            }

        }catch (SQLException e){
            try{
                File file = new File("E:/1.txt");
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            try {
                e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            }finally {
                printWriter.close();
            }

            }catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }finally {
            closeConnection(connection);
            closePreparedStatement(preparedStatement);
            closeResultSet(resultSet);
        }
    return id_sale;
}
```

Подключение к базе данных

```
db.host = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/esteamerbase?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Метод формирующий текущую дату и приводящий его к типу sql Date

```
public Date getNowDateToDate(){
    String date = "";
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    date += calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-";
    if ((calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)<10){
        date += "0" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    }else {
        date += (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    }
    if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)<10){
        date += "-0" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }else{
        date += "-" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    return Date.valueOf(date);
}
```

Суть в том, что я отправляю на запись в Базу данных 2019-02-01, а мне записывается 2019-01-31. Если в код генерирования текущей даты ко дню добавить +1 (2019-02-02), то в Базу записывается 2019-02-01. Но это не выход. Со временен разница в 3 часа. Глобальный часовой пояс в MySql настроен на SYSTEM.
 
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Вероятно, что-то с настройкой таймзон. В строке подключения к бд у вас там настройки осознано прописаны? И да, используейте классы из пакета `java.time` для работы со датами.

Comment: @iksuy дело в том, что без этой настройки сервер выкидывает ошибку java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'RTZ 2 (????)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в чем была проблема. Проблема была в timezone в СУБД MySQL. Как только установил глобальную зону на +3 часа все сразу стало корректно отрабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передать дату не в привычном формате а в unixTime.

```
long data = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

или

```
int data2 = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis())/1000;
```

или

```
int data3 = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis())/1000/60/24;
```

Если будет разрыв в будет в несколько часов значит вы на верном пути.
Пробуйте один из этих вариантов.
У меня была идентичная проблема, помог вариант2 но мне надо было дата+время.